# Calculate salary in exist

Tags: sql

I have table employee and table family. Let's say that employee has name column and salary column.
Then I have to calculate their salary: 3% to salary of employee who have family and 2% to all who don't have family.
Do you have any idea how to do this? I know that I have to use exist but I don't know how to calculate the salary.

This table employee:

```
employeeID int, 
Name varchar(10), 
PhoneNumber varchar(20), 
ICNumber varchar(15), 
Salary decimal(5,2), 
primary key(employeeId));
```

This is table family

```
familyId int, 
name varchar(20), 
family varchar(20), 
address varchar(25), 
phoneNumber varchar(20), 
employeeID int, 
primary key (employeeID), 
FOREIGN KEY (employeeID) REFERENCES Employee(employeeID))
```

Comment: you'll need to post your table model to have any chance of getting a reasonable answer.

Comment: This table employee: employeeID int,
Name varchar(10),
PhoneNumber varchar(20),
ICNumber varchar(15),
Salary decimal(5,2),
primary key(employeeId)); end this is table family familyId int,
name  varchar(20),
family varchar(20),
address varchar(25),
phoneNumber varchar(20),
employeeID int,
primary key (employeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (employeeID) REFERENCES Employee(employeeID))

Answer (score 0):

> The SQL EXISTS condition is used in combination with a subquery and is considered to be met, if the subquery returns at least one row. It can be used in a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php

So let's see how we can use that to determine whether to update a particular salary by 3% or 2%.

For employees with a family:

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET Salary = 1.03 * Salary 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Family WHERE Employee.employeeId = Family.employeeId
)
```

I'll leave the other case as an exercise to the reader ([hint](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/not.php)).

**UPDATE**

If you just want to select what the new salary should be

```
SELECT employeeId, 1.03 * Salary As NewSalary FROM Employee
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Family WHERE Employee.employeeId = Family.employeeId
)
```

Comment: Ok. How about in select statement? If in update you can set the salary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you wanted to select the +3% or +2% value rather than update?

```
SELECT
  employeeid,
  salary,
  salary * loading_factor AS loading
FROM (
  SELECT
    employeeid,
    salary,
    CASE
      WHEN EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM family f WHERE f.employeeID = e.employeeID THEN 0.03
      ELSE 0.02
    END AS loading_factor
  FROM employee e
)
```

You can do it without the sub-select, but I thought it would read easier. If you want the total new salary amount rather than the increment, change the 0.02 / 0.03 to 1.02 / 1.03.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I try not to use `exists` or `not exists` clauses when possible. In your case, you can get your desired result with a *left outer join*:

```
select
  emp.name,
  emp.salary,
  case when fam.employeeID is null 
       then 0.02
       else 0.03 
  end  * emp.salary  salary_adjusted
from
  employee   emp    left join
  family     fam on emp.employeeID = fam.employeeID;
```

Comment: Why do you choose for not using exist? What is your consideration? Is it exist not good from the performance side?

Comment: Yes, I had been hit a few times by poor performance when I used `in` and/or `not in`.